# Issue with blockquote when using float

Tags: html, css, blockquote

In my html page, I have an image which has been floated left. All texts are supposed to appear on the right and the bottom of the image, this is working as expected.

Only problem I am facing is with the blockquotes. Expected result : on the right of the image-> start quotation mark - quote - end quotation mark.
Actual result: Start quotation mark is missing.

Please note that if I put all the text including blockquote in a div element and float it, this issue disappears. But I don't want to float this element.

It would be really helpful if someone can refer this code and suggest any solution: [Anshul's html](https://codepen.io/Anshulrai/pen/veaZjO)

```css
.contain img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding-right: 25px;*/
      
    }
    .main-div{
      float:left; 
      width: 40%
     }
    
    .thin-black-border {
        border-color: #686464;
        border-width: 05px;
        border-style: solid;
      }
    
    .header{
      font: 200 80px'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #F4E6E6;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    
    /* =Structure
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    p {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    p:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    /* =Blockquote
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    blockquote {
        position: relative;
        marign: 0px;
       padding: 30px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
      /*display:inline-block;*/
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
        position: absolute;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 120px;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    blockquote:before {
      
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        content: "\201C";
    }
    blockquote:after {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        content: "\201D";
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px;background-color:#3B3838" >
  <h1 class="text-center header">Madhubala</h1>
</div>
<div class = "main-div contain"> <img src="https://nehamalude.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/madhubala.jpg"/> </div>
<!-- If I don't comment the code below, start quotation mark shows up --> 
<!--<div style="float:left; width: 60%; "> -->

<p><blockquote><span title = "Theatre Arts - American magazine"> The Biggest Star in the World - and she's not in Beverly Hills!</span></blockquote></p>
<p>Text.....</p>
<!--</div> -->

</body>
```

Comment: It is not "missing", it is simply _underneath_ the image, because that is where the left corner of the blockquote element still is - only the _inline contents_ of the blockquote are floated around the image, not the blockquote as a block element itself. You either need to change that (make the blockquote element go next to the image in its entirety, for example via an appropriate margin-left), or not absolutely position the quotes based on the blockquote.

Comment: Removing 'Position: Absolute' solved the issue! Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue with blockquote when using float**

just remove  position: absolute; in blockquote:before, blockquote:after class

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">


.contain img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;*/

}
.main-div{
  float:left; 
  width: 40%
 }

.thin-black-border {
    border-color: #686464;
    border-width: 05px;
    border-style: solid;
  }

.header{
  font: 200 80px'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #F4E6E6;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

/* =Structure
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* =Blockquote
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
blockquote {
    position: relative;
    marign: 0px;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  /*display:inline-block;*/
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 120px;
    line-height: 1;
}
blockquote:before {

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "\201C";
}
blockquote:after {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "\201D";
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px;background-color:#3B3838" > 
  <h1 class="text-center header">Madhubala</h1>
 </div>

<div class = "main-div contain">
<img src="https://nehamalude.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/madhubala.jpg"/>
</div>
<!-- If I don't comment the code below, start quotation mark shows up -->
<!--<div style="float:left; width: 60%; "> -->

  <p>
   <blockquote><span title = "Theatre Arts - American magazine"> The Biggest Star in the World - and she's not in Beverly Hills!</span></blockquote>
  </p>
<p> Text.....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the quotation mark doesn't show up is because your blockquote takes up 100% of the container width. That means it starts below the floatet image. The text itself adjusts to fit the floated image, but the quotation mark is set to be positioned absolutely:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

and therefore starts at the very left of the container, below the image. 
If you remove the absolute positioning, the question mark appears at the start of the text.